# Average in complexity

Tags: mean

Lets say that complexity if individual is ranked in ordinal scale as : 
1 = simple 2= moderate 3= complex 4 = very complex, how would i indicate the average of complexity by taking from 100 respondents? Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more?

Answer (score 2):

Ordinal scales don't have means, but they do have medians and modes. If you assume interval scale - basically, assuming that (moderate - simple) = (complex - moderate) = (verycomplex - complex)  -- then you could calculate an average from those scores in the usual manner.